# Scikit-learn linear model fit after running matplotlib plot returns Value error

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I am running the code from [first chapter](https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml/blob/master/01_the_machine_learning_landscape.ipynb) of Aurélien Géron's  Hands-on Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn and TensorFlow.

The code that I am trying to run is:

```py
# Code example
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sklearn.linear_model

# Load the data
oecd_bli = pd.read_csv(datapath + "oecd_bli_2015.csv", thousands=',')
gdp_per_capita = pd.read_csv(datapath + "gdp_per_capita.csv",thousands=',',delimiter='\t',
                             encoding='latin1', na_values="n/a")

# Prepare the data
country_stats = prepare_country_stats(oecd_bli, gdp_per_capita)
X = np.c_[country_stats["GDP per capita"]]
y = np.c_[country_stats["Life satisfaction"]]

# Visualize the data
country_stats.plot(kind='scatter', x="GDP per capita", y='Life satisfaction')
plt.show()

# Select a linear model
model = sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression()

# Train the model
model.fit(X, y)
```

It fails at the step `model.fit(X, y)` with the below traceback:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
     23 
     24 # # Train the model
---> 25 model.fit(X, y)
     26 
     27 # # Make a prediction for Cyprus

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\venv\ds\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_base.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    531         else:
    532             self.coef_, self._residues, self.rank_, self.singular_ = \
--> 533                 linalg.lstsq(X, y)
    534             self.coef_ = self.coef_.T
    535 

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\venv\ds\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\basic.py in lstsq(a, b, cond, overwrite_a, overwrite_b, check_finite, lapack_driver)
   1223             raise LinAlgError("SVD did not converge in Linear Least Squares")
   1224         if info < 0:
-> 1225             raise ValueError('illegal value in %d-th argument of internal %s'
   1226                              % (-info, lapack_driver))
   1227         resids = np.asarray([], dtype=x.dtype)

ValueError: illegal value in 4-th argument of internal None
```

However, when I re-run the fit function without the `plt.show()` command, it works fine:

```
country_stats.plot(kind='scatter', x="GDP per capita", y='Life satisfaction')

model.fit(X, y) # works OK

# # Make a prediction for Cyprus
X_new = [[22587]]  # Cyprus' GDP per capita
print(model.predict(X_new)) # outputs [[ 5.96242338]]
```

The behavior is super odd. Not sure if it is due to my package versions. Here are my current package versions:

```
pip freeze | grep -E "numpy|pandas|scipy|matplotlib|sci"
matplotlib==3.2.1
numpy==1.18.4
pandas==0.25.3
scikit-image==0.16.2
scikit-learn==0.22
scipy==1.4.1
```

Comment: Is the `plt.show()` indeed missing from your second snippet (as opposed to the first one), or you have just forgotten to include it?

Comment: You are right. plt.show() is missing in my 2nd snippet and when I include it, it breaks again. Looks like plt.show() is causing this issue. I will update my case description accordingly.

Comment: Another potential problem could be a broke scipy (linalg) installation. Sklearn uses `scipy.sparse.linalg.LinearOperator`.

Comment: So, i run the code from the link you posted and everything seems to be workig fine. Even with the `plt.show()` in the code. I run the code 10 times. 10 sucessful trials. Try to double-check the `X`, `y`data and re-install `numpy` and `scipy`

Comment: make a complet new kernel and run it again, it should work, the error indicates an empty array somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have run the code 10 times and it has finished successfully. 
It seems that you have missed something in your code.
Full code, 10 trials of the code part that breaks, results are printed.

```
# Common imports
import numpy as np
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sklearn.linear_model

# to make this notebook's output stable across runs
np.random.seed(42)

# To plot pretty figures
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mpl.rc('axes', labelsize=14)
mpl.rc('xtick', labelsize=12)
mpl.rc('ytick', labelsize=12)

def prepare_country_stats(oecd_bli, gdp_per_capita):
    oecd_bli = oecd_bli[oecd_bli["INEQUALITY"]=="TOT"]
    oecd_bli = oecd_bli.pivot(index="Country", columns="Indicator", values="Value")
    gdp_per_capita.rename(columns={"2015": "GDP per capita"}, inplace=True)
    gdp_per_capita.set_index("Country", inplace=True)
    full_country_stats = pd.merge(left=oecd_bli, right=gdp_per_capita,
                                  left_index=True, right_index=True)
    full_country_stats.sort_values(by="GDP per capita", inplace=True)
    remove_indices = [0, 1, 6, 8, 33, 34, 35]
    keep_indices = list(set(range(36)) - set(remove_indices))
    return full_country_stats[["GDP per capita", 'Life satisfaction']].iloc[keep_indices]


# Load the data
oecd_bli = pd.read_csv("oecd_bli_2015.csv", thousands=',')
gdp_per_capita = pd.read_csv("gdp_per_capita.csv",thousands=',',delimiter='\t',
                             encoding='latin1', na_values="n/a")


oecd_bli.head(3)
#  LOCATION    Country INDICATOR  ... Value Flag Codes            Flags
#0      AUS  Australia   HO_BASE  ...   1.1          E  Estimated value
#1      AUT    Austria   HO_BASE  ...   1.0        NaN              NaN
#2      BEL    Belgium   HO_BASE  ...   2.0        NaN              NaN


gdp_per_capita.head(3)
#                                            Subject Descriptor  ... #Estimates Start After
#Country                                                         ...
#Afghanistan  Gross domestic product per capita, current prices  ...                #2013.0
#Albania      Gross domestic product per capita, current prices  ...                #2010.0
#Algeria      Gross domestic product per capita, current prices  ...                #2014.0


# Prepare the data
country_stats = prepare_country_stats(oecd_bli, gdp_per_capita)
X = np.c_[country_stats["GDP per capita"]]
y = np.c_[country_stats["Life satisfaction"]]

X[0:3]
#array([[ 9054.914],
#       [ 9437.372],
#       [12239.894]])

y[0:3]
#array([[6. ],
#       [5.6],
#       [4.9]])

results = list()
for i in range(10):
    # Visualize the data
    country_stats.plot(kind='scatter', x="GDP per capita", y='Life satisfaction')
    plt.show()

    # Select a linear model
    model = sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression()

    # Train the model
    model.fit(X, y)

    # Make a prediction for Cyprus
    X_new = [[22587]]  # Cyprus' GDP per capita
    results.append(model.predict(X_new))


print(results)
#[array([[5.96242338]]),
# array([[5.96242338]]),
# array([[5.96242338]]),
# array([[5.96242338]]),
# array([[5.96242338]]),
# array([[5.96242338]]),
# array([[5.96242338]]),
# array([[5.96242338]]),
# array([[5.96242338]]),
# array([[5.96242338]])]
```

And:

```
pip freeze | grep -E "numpy|pandas|scipy|matplotlib|sci"
matplotlib==3.1.2
numpy==1.17.4
pandas==0.25.3
pandas-flavor==0.2.0
scikit-learn==0.22.1
scikit-plot==0.3.7
scipy==1.4.1
```